# Python class with many default values

Tags: python

I'm creating a class with many default values, but I want to be able to change any of them from the `__init__` function.  I'd like to do something like:

```
class foo:
    settings = {'bar': 1, 'baz': 2, . . . . }

    def __init__(input, **kwargs):
        settings.update(kwargs)
        for key in settings.keys():
            self.<key> = settings[key]
        . . .
```

but I'm not sure how to implement that last line.  I can rewrite the whole class using `self.settings['bar']` instead of `self.bar` but that seems a bit wordy and confusing.  I though I could set all of the defaults before `__init__` and then do

```
for key in kwargs.keys():
    f = operator.attrgetter(key)
    f(self) = kwargs[key]
```

But that gives a `SyntaxError` of `can't assign to function call`

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: The common way of providing default values is `def __init__(self, bar=1, baz=2, . . .):`. Why would you do it differently? It looks unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Goyo The defaults in some cases are large arrays/objects  that I'll have to load from an external file anyway, so I figured I could load everything from one pickled dictionary/tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `setattr(object, attrname, value)`.
You may use the following code:

```
class foo:
    settings = {'bar': 1, 'baz': 2, . . . . }

    def __init__(input, **kwargs):
        settings.update(kwargs)
        for key in settings.keys():
            setattr(self, key, settings[key])
```

Comment: Thanks, tht's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setattr` function of python. Below is the example:

```
setattr(self, <name>, <value>)
```

In your case you can try below code:

```
setattr(self, key, settings[key])
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) is the detail document